# Solution of a particular Trigonometric Integral

Tags: integration, trigonometry, special-functions

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this trigonometric integral?
$$\int\frac{dx}{(a+bx)\sin(x)}$$
I have tried so many strategy but they don't work.

Comment: What strategies have you tried?

Comment: If it was a definite integral of the form:

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(a + bx)\sin(x)} \:dx $$

Then it should be solvable with Ramanujan's Master Theorem.